# How do I toggle button images when clicked?

Tags: swift

I want to change my play button to a pause button when clicked. And vice-versa.

Here is my code:

var toggleState = 1

```
@IBAction func playPauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {

      var playBut = UIButton()

    if toggleState == 1 {  

        player.play()

        toggleState = 2

    } else {

        player.pause()

        toggleState = 1 
    }

}
```

I've tried (and had no luck with) adding:

```
@IBAction func playPauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var playBtn = sender as UIButton

    if toggleState == 1 {

        player.play()

        toggleState = 2

        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

    } else {

        player.pause()

        toggleState = 1

        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

    }

}
```

All this did was crash my app when I click play. Could somebody help me?

Comment: If player.playing {....}

Answer (score 2):

The logic that you attempted should have worked. The only suspicious thing there is the cast, but Swift lets you eliminate it by declaring the sender parameter of the exact type:

```
let imgPlay = UIImage(named:"play.png")
let imgPause = UIImage(named:"pause.png")

@IBAction func playPauseButton(playBtn: UIButton) {
    if toggleState == 1 {
        player.play()
        toggleState = 2
        playBtn.setImage(imgPlay,forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        player.pause()
        toggleState = 1
        playBtn.setImage(imgPause,forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

I also moved image creation out of the handler to avoid performing the same task repeatedly.

Comment: It's still crashing. I get SIGABRT on class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: @BenKelsey Does it stop crashing if you remove `setImage` calls from both branches?

Comment: If you mean delete everything after .setImage on both lines, then yes, it stops crashing.

Comment: @BenKelsey That's very odd... Could you set a breakpoint and see if `imgPlay` and `imgPause` are both non-nil?

Comment: I'm so sorry but I've just started programming about two weeks ago and I don't know how to use breakpoints yet. I just Googled them so I know what they do and how to set them, but I don't know how to use them to check for non-nils.

Comment: @BenKelsey Set a breakpoint on the `if` line and run your code in the emulator. Click the button; breakpoint should hit, and you will be in the debugger. Now move the mouse pointer over a variable to examine its current value.

Comment: @BenKelsey That's the problem then: it looks like the system cannot find your images. Please make sure that you have properly included them in your project; names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I see where that went wrong. I was using a bar button instead of a normal button. I just moved my button out of the toolbar, imported two png files and it works.

Out of curiosity, do you know how I would change a bar button in the same manner?

Comment: @BenKelsey I am not sure if the placement of the button in the toolbar was the problem - I think it's the missing png files. As long as the type matches (i.e. your button is actually a `UIButton`) the code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct TabbarView: View {
    @State var isCameraOn: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
                    self.isCameraOn.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: isCameraOn ? "video.circle.fill": "video.slash.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                })
    }
}
```